# EM or Percentages for Responsive Website?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Currently I have a completed website which currently isn't responsive most of the values for things are using pixels with a one or two using percentages and em.

Should I convert the pixel values to percentages or em values? Does one or the other actually make a difference. This is my first time making a website responsive so still sort of confused on the subject but am following this tutorial:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-get-started-with-responsive-web-design/

Comment: For font-size it doesn't matter, for boxes use percents (you don't know how many `em`s you are able to put into viewport). For high resolution you can you `em`s as a `max-width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `%` as much you can for `width` for use main `container` or `div` also use `min-width and` `max-width`, keep font sizes on px or em don't change that values to `%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
the best way to fix this using media queries
media only screen 
and (min-width : 1366px) 
and (max-width : 1440px) {
    .page-heading .title{
    //put your font size 
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1991px) 
and (max-width : 1365px) {
    .page-heading .title{
    //put your font size(change according to screen size) 
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1280px) 
and (max-width : 1990px){
    .page-heading .title{
    //put your font size(change according to screen size) 
    }
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 481px) 
and (max-width : 767px) {
    .page-heading .title{
    //put your font size(change according to screen size) 
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .page-heading .title{
    //put your font size(change according to screen size) 
    }
}

YOU CAN CHANGE MIN AND MAX WIDTH ACCORDING TO THE SCREEN SIZES AND REDUCE THE FONT SIZE RESPECTIVELY
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the information and I will follow all your advice guys and come back with the results.